# How to check response of every element in list comprehension

Tags: erlang

In the following code, I want to check result of every calling of `start_item` is `ok` or not. 
It is impossible to add `ok=` before `start_item`.

```
start_item_group(Community_code,Category_code,Group_code)->
    [
     start_item(Community_code,Category_code,Item_seq_no)
     ||
     {_Community_code,_Category_code,Item_seq_no} 
     <-
     dis_scan:get_group_item(Community_code,Category_code,Group_code),    
    ok.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar before, but in a different way.  I too needed to check the result of an expression.  The benefit of my trick is that you don't need to check it yourself, pattern matching does it for you.  The key to the trick is to use lists:foldl. An example is below.

```
check_group(Community_code,Category_code,Group_code) ->
    Group = dis_scan:get_group_item(Community_code,Category_code,Group_code),
    StartItems = [ start_item(Community_code,Category_code,Item_seq_no) 
               || {_, _, Item_seq_no } <- Group ],
    ok = lists:foldl(fun check_start_item/2, ok, StartItems),
    exit(normal).

check_start_item(StartItem, ok) -> 
    ## Return ok if item is ok, {error, Reason} otherwise.
    ok.
```

If on the other hand you need to group the items by the result returned from the check then use lists:partition.

```
check_group(Community_code,Category_code,Group_code) ->
    Group = dis_scan:get_group_item(Community_code,Category_code,Group_code),
    StartItems = [ start_item(Community_code,Category_code,Item_seq_no) 
               || {_, _, Item_seq_no } <- Group ],
    {GoodItems, BadItems} = lists:partition(fun check_start_item/1, StartItems),
    case BadItems of 
        [] -> exit(normal);
         _ -> error({bad_start_items, BadItems})
    end.

check_start_item(StartItem) -> 
    ## Return true if item is ok, false otherwise.
    true.
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is possible to check which `start_item` calls do not return `ok` by moving the pattern match into the list comprehension as a filter! Personally, I'd do as follows:

```
start_item_group(Community_code,Category_code,Group_code)->
  Failed = [
    Item ||
    {_Comm_code, _Cat_code, Item} <- dis_scan:get_group_item(Community_code,Category_code,Group_code),
    ok =/= start_item(Community_code, Category_code, Item)
  ],
  do_stuff_with(Failed).
```

Comment: Thank you. It is an another method.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use lists:foreach. foreach get function as a parameter and you can write all you want in those function.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a wrapper function that calls and check the result of start_item's function evaluation and do whatever needs to be done if not 'ok' (or 'ok'):

```
start_item_check(ok) ->
  %% return/do whatever needs to be done if response is ok;
start_item_check(not_ok) ->
  %% return/do whatever needs to be done if response is not ok;
start_item_check(StartItemResponse) ->
  %% do whatever needs to be done if not 'ok' nor 'not_ok';
  %% it's up to your business logic.

start_item_group(Community_code,Category_code,Group_code) ->
  [
    start_item_check(start_item(Community_code,Category_code,Item_seq_no))
    ||
    {_Community_code,_Category_code,Item_seq_no}
    <-
    dis_scan:get_group_item(Community_code,Category_code,Group_code)
  ].
```

If you want to filter out elements based on what 'start_item' function is returning, you could simply use lists:filter on the list that you produced using your implementation.
That's what you can do if you *want* to keep using lists comprehension; otherwise you can use lists:foreach as W55tKQbuRu28Q4xv prev. suggested.